# Try to access and change camera pixel values on Vuforia and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I would like to access the camera (pc or mobile) before recognition is done.
I want to change the value of the pixels in function of the brightness and the contrast.
My goal is to optimize the tracking with vuforia by stretching or equalizing the values ​​in the form of a histogram when changing light.

I retrieve pixel values from the [Vuforia camera image](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-the-Camera) :

I manage to recover the values ​​of the pixels of the image but I can not modify them.

I tried this method for set all pixel at 0 value on OnTrackablesUpdated method : `image.Pixels.SetValue(byte value, index);`
My recognition work again it should not work if all my pixels are at zero.

How I can change pixels camera values ?

Here is my code :

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;
using System;

public class CameraImageAccess : MonoBehaviour
{
private Image.PIXEL_FORMAT mPixelFormat = Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.UNKNOWN_FORMAT;

private bool mAccessCameraImage = true;
private bool mFormatRegistered = false;

void Start()
{
    mPixelFormat = Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888; // Use RGB888 for mobile

    // Register Vuforia life-cycle callbacks:
    VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
    VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterTrackablesUpdatedCallback(OnTrackablesUpdated);
    VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnPause);
}

void OnVuforiaStarted()
{
    // Try register camera image format
    if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, true))
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully registered pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
        mFormatRegistered = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError(
            "\nFailed to register pixel format: " + mPixelFormat.ToString() +
            "\nThe format may be unsupported by your device." +
            "\nConsider using a different pixel format.\n");
        mFormatRegistered = false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Called each time the Vuforia state is updated
/// </summary>
void OnTrackablesUpdated()
{
    if (mFormatRegistered)
    {
        if (mAccessCameraImage)
        {
            Vuforia.Image image = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(mPixelFormat);

            if (image != null)
            {
                byte[] pixels = image.Pixels;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when app is paused / resumed
/// </summary>
void OnPause(bool paused)
{
    if (paused)
    {
        Debug.Log("App was paused");
        UnregisterFormat();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("App was resumed");
        RegisterFormat();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Register the camera pixel format
/// </summary>
void RegisterFormat()
{
    if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, true))
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully registered camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
        mFormatRegistered = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to register camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
        mFormatRegistered = false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Unregister the camera pixel format (e.g. call this when app is paused)
/// </summary>
void UnregisterFormat()
{
    Debug.Log("Unregistering camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
    CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, false);
    mFormatRegistered = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to set pixel values?

Comment: You can try to get the data of the Vuforia camera, edit the pixels and apply the new texture on a Raw Image or Mesh that covers all the screen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499314/hololens-how-to-get-webcam-texture-2d-from-vuforia/60170648?noredirect=1#comment121718848_60170648