# HoloLens - How to get webcam texture 2D from Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I'm developing a Vuforia app for HoloLens by using Unity.

This app displays a simple 3D Object when an image target is detected.

I'm also using the fm Exhibition Tool Pack hololens from the Unity Asset Store in order to stream the app running on HoloLens to a PC.

Everything works fine but when i stream the app to PC i see the 3D Unity scene instead of the room.

So i've tried to get the webcam texture and attach it to a cube inside the scene but the vuforia ARCamera get somehow conflict with it and i can't see anything on the cube. Instead when i run the app inside the Unity Simulator i see myself on the cube.

Is there a way to get the webcam texture 2D from Vuforia and attach it to a GameObject inside the scene? Maybe with the Vuforia.Image class? But i don't know how it works.

Comment: As far as i know, only one process can access the camera at a time. As long as you use Vuforia and it is streaming, i dont think you can access the cam at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Below scripts are compatible with FMETP STREAM.
The scripts are tested on mobile.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VuforiaCamAccess : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool mAccessCameraImage = true;
    public RawImage rawImage;
    public GameObject Mesh;
    private Texture2D texture;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private Vuforia.PIXEL_FORMAT mPixelFormat = Vuforia.PIXEL_FORMAT.GRAYSCALE;
#else
    private Vuforia.PIXEL_FORMAT mPixelFormat =  Vuforia.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888;
#endif

    private bool mFormatRegistered = false;

    void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.R8, false);
#else
        texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
#endif
        // Register Vuforia life-cycle callbacks:
        Vuforia.VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
        Vuforia.VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnPause);
        Vuforia.VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterTrackablesUpdatedCallback(OnTrackablesUpdated);
    }

    private void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        // Try register camera image format
        if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, true))
        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully registered pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
            mFormatRegistered = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to register pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString() +
                "\n the format may be unsupported by your device;" +
                "\n consider using a different pixel format.");
            mFormatRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnPause(bool paused)
    {
        if (paused)
        {
            Debug.Log("App was paused");
            UnregisterFormat();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("App was resumed");
            RegisterFormat();
        }
    }

    private void OnTrackablesUpdated()
    {
        //skip if still loading image to texture2d
        if (LoadingTexture) return;

        if (mFormatRegistered)
        {
            if (mAccessCameraImage)
            {
                Vuforia.Image image = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(mPixelFormat);
                //if (image != null && image.IsValid())
                if (image != null)
                {
                    byte[] pixels = image.Pixels;
                    int width = image.Width;
                    int height = image.Height;
                    StartCoroutine(SetTexture(pixels, width, height));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool LoadingTexture = false;
    IEnumerator SetTexture(byte[] pixels, int width, int height)
    {
        if (!LoadingTexture)
        {
            LoadingTexture = true;
            if (pixels != null && pixels.Length > 0)
            {
                if (texture.width != width || texture.height != height)
                {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                    texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.R8, false);
#else
                    texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
#endif
                }

                texture.LoadRawTextureData(pixels);
                texture.Apply();

                if (rawImage != null)
                {
                    rawImage.texture = texture;
                    rawImage.material.mainTexture = texture;
                }

                if (Mesh != null) Mesh.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
            }
            yield return null;
            LoadingTexture = false;
        }
    }

    private void UnregisterFormat()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unregistering camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, false);
        mFormatRegistered = false;
    }

    private void RegisterFormat()
    {
        if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(mPixelFormat, true))
        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully registered camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
            mFormatRegistered = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to register camera pixel format " + mPixelFormat.ToString());
            mFormatRegistered = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. Do you know by any chance why the texture in the editor is red and how to fix it?

Comment: as far as I remember, it returns only mono channel in editor by default.
It's Vuforia limit at the time I tested.